# Multiple jQuery Cycle slideshows get superimposed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cycle

I'm using the jQuery cycle plugin to create multiple slideshows on a single page (which, once I get this problem figured out, will be started/stopped by mouse hover -- yeah, I know there are 9 slideshows on the page).

Problem is, when I tell more than one slideshow to start cycling, whichever ones I call cycle() on get superimposed.  So, all the images from slide 1 are superimposed, then they all transition to slide 2, etc.  I can tell they're being superimposed because the first slide of each slideshow contains a transparent PNG.

This happens whether I call cycle() in a jQuery each() iterator, or even if I call it by hand on just two or three of the containers with a jQuery id selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your CSS:

```
.column { position: relative }
```

The Cycle plugin is setting an `absolute` positioning on the slideshows, which will be in relation to the first parent element that has either `position: relative` or `position: absolute`. So by setting `position: relative` on the `.column` class, it contains the slideshow to its `0,0` coordinates and subsequently keeps them from overlapping each other.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Your suggestion worked perfectly, though I was a little nervous about messing with the positioning of my CSS grid, so I added a wrapper div to the slideshow and applied position: absolute to that.  Works great in Firefox.